# Find the function of two overlapping polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials

I have two polynomial functions that overlap each other, and I'm trying to determine the function that represents both of them together exactly.

Example:

$$( (x-4)(x-3)(x-2) + 10 ) + ( (x-1)^2 + 15)$$

I had thought the solution would be

$$(x-4)(x-3)(x-2)(x-1) + 25$$

but graphing technology shows that I am way off. How can I find the function for two overlapping polynomials?

[image]

EDIT>>>
As seen in the image above, I want a single function that represents one continuous line from the beginning of the first 3rd order function (purple) to the end of the 2nd order function (black)

NOTE: This graph does not use the above polynomials, and is only for example purposes. The polynomials in the graph are -(x-9)(x-5) and (x-1)(x-2)(x-5)
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "overlap" and what by "both of them together exactly" ??

Comment: Neither graph represents $(x-1)^2+15$ since that's a strictly positive, convex function. Sorry, but it's impossible to guess what it is that you mean to ask.

Comment: Apart that "beginning" and "end" are not so clear (do you mean for $-\infty <x < \infty$ ?), where do you want the "enveloping" curve leave one function and land onto the other ? at the crossing near $x=4$ or at that in $x=5$ ? and which are exactly the two functions since you draw that they both are $0$ at $x=5$ ??

Comment: If I understand your question the single function for the "overlap" won't be a polynomial (since the two pieces have different slopes where they cross). It won't have a simple algebraic formula.

Comment: @bigcodeszzer Is it [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=max(+(x%E2%88%924)(x%E2%88%923)(x%E2%88%922)%2B10,+(x-1)%5E2%2B15+)) what you call "*overlap*" maybe?

Comment: @GCab Where, for fn-purple, x<=5 and for fn-black, x>=5. Where the curve is smooth, the exact definitions variable, so long as the curve joins both vertices without any extra turns.

Comment: edit - another image added

Comment: @bigcodeszzer How do those graphs relate to the polynomials you posted? Neither of those has a zero at $x=5$.

Comment: Oh. My bad. They are different.

Comment: Edited, fixed. See note in question

Comment: Do you mean this maybe? $$
\begin{align}
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
(x-1)(x-2)(x-5) \quad & x \lt 5\\
-(x-9)(x-5) & x \ge 5
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @dxiv Well, yes, but with only one function and no restrictions.

Comment: @bigcodeszzer What I posted *is* one single function. If you mean only one polynomial expression across the entire range, then that doesn't exist.

Comment: @dxiv Why doesn't it exist? Are there not third order functions that take the shape of the two combined. I'm certain I've seen some that do.

Comment: @bigcodeszzer Too long for a comment, posted as an answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question posted by OP in a comment, the following proves that given two polynomials $g(x),h(x)$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(a)=h(a)$  the function defined piecewise as:

$$
\begin{align}
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\;\;g(x) & \quad x \lt a \\
\;\;h(x) & \quad x \ge a
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

is a polynomial only if $g(x) \equiv h(x)$.

**Proof 1.**   Suppose $f$ is a polynomial. Then $f-g$ is a polynomial as well. But $f(x)-g(x)=0$ for $\forall x \lt a$ so $f-g$ has infinitely many roots, which implies that $f-g \equiv 0$ is the null polynomial, therefore $f \equiv g$. By a similar argument $f \equiv h$ so in the end $f \equiv g \equiv h$.

**Proof 2.**   Any polynomial is infinitely differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$. Assuming $f$ is a polynomial, it can be represented by its Taylor series around $a$ as $f(x) = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n$. For all derivatives of $f$ to be continuous at $a$, the lateral limits must match i.e. $g^{(n)}(a)=h^{(n)}(a)$ for $\forall n \ge 0$. But this implies that the Taylor series of $g,h$ at $a$ are identical, so $g \equiv h$.

Comment: To whoever downvoted, please first read the full context then reconsider.

Answer (score 1):

You can expand each product then collect coefficients for terms that are the same degree.

If you expand $(x-4)(x-3)(x-2) + 10$ you get

$$x^3-9x^2+26x-14$$

Doing this to the term $(x-1)^2 + 15$, you get

$$x^2-2x+16$$

Adding the two yields

$$x^3-8x^2+24x+2$$

Comment: seems you understood what OP is asking: can you make that explicit ?

Comment: Do you mean multiply both functions together? Because I just used a polynomial calculator to add those two example functions together (see image) and the result was incorrect.

Comment: I used an automatic factor algorithm, as well as a multiplier and an adder on the two polynomials and none of the results were correct.

Comment: @bigcodeszzer "automatic factor algorithm" .. are you sure of what you want to do ? and what you mean to say ?

Comment: Reverse factor algorithm. And I checked with the graphing calculator also.

Comment: I really think you should take a moment to think through and understand exactly what you want, then properly explain it to us.

Comment: The question has been edited.

Comment: x^3-8x^2+24x+2 does not graph to the correct answer.

Comment: See dxiv's comment. There is no answer to your question.